# how to launch Bootstrap Modal as sign in with validatoin?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a login modal which is a partial view, then i can pop up window for user to login in anytime.below is how it looks like.

```
@model LeduInfo.Models.LoginModel




     <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"> Login </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                          <div class="modal-body">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @id="signinForm"}))
                        {
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Account creation was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">User Name</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @name = "inputUser", @class = "form-control", @id = "inputUser", @placeholder = "User Name" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.UserName)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { @name = "inputPassword", @class = "form-control", @id = "inputPassword", @placeholder = "Password", @type = "password" })   
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Password)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <label class="checkbox">
                                       Remember me @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                                        <span class="span9">  @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account")   </span>

                                    </label>

                                     <button type="button" id="submit_btn" class="btn btn-primary" >sign in</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        } 


                    </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
```

but now, i fount it will submit form when click on sign in button and window closed, that is not what i wanted, then i add jquery code as below to manually submit form. but if in this case, then i can not got info return from server for validation, how can i fix it with submit form but not close modal?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
    $('#submit_btn').click(function () {
        var form = $('#singinForm');
        $("#signinForm").validate({

            // Specify the validation rules
            rules: {
                inputUser: "required",
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6
                }
            },


            // Specify the validation error messages
            messages: {
                inputUser: "Please enter your first name",
                password: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least {0} characters long"
                },
            },

            submitHandler: function (form) {

                form.submit();
                $('#signinForm').find("#submit_btn").attr("disabled", true).attr("value", "Submitting...");
            }
        });



        }
    });
```

Comment: $('#submit_btn').click(function () {
} why are you attaching click event multiple times?

Comment: oh, sorry, that is the way i using to handle click event, in real situation, i just use one of them, will modify content now, thanks.

Comment: from your above code i am seeing you are attaching same click event two times.

Comment: yes, now it's not used any more